# Sync Twitter / Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter

Twitter to Facebook

I did some research here and on google, but not successful - I am looking a way to sync my Twitter account with Facebook. Meaning that new Tweets get automatically posted on Facebook

Regards,
CI

Comment: this is where you need to start reading: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work.

1. Login in Twitter and Facebook.
2. In Twitter, click your profile icon and choose "Settings and privacy".
3. Choose "Apps".
4. Choose Facebook Connect and Click connect to Facebook.
   Pop up confirmation will occur just CLICK "Continue as " button.
   And you will see this message:
   "Twitter would like to post to Facebook for you.
   Who can see Twitter's posts on your Timeline?" -- Set who you want to see your posts AND then Click OK.

"Facebook Connect
Your account is connected to Facebook.
Allow Twitter to: (JUST make sure you checked the 2 checkbox)

(check this)post retweets to Facebook

(check this)post to my Facebook profile

Allow posting to one of your pages."

4. You can now test some retweet or tweet then check your Facebook account.